# (C) Access to normal speaker in PC and play WAV through it

Tags: c, windows, audio, wav, speaker

I finished my WAV file format structure on C and I can load any WAV file with function. But I don't know how to play data on speakers. 
I couldn't find any examples or something on Google about using speaker. 
I suppose this is something about ports stuff and using it, but i can't find information about speaker ports. 
I'm using Windows 2000 for programming, but I think it doesn't change anything. If it's impossible, on my normal computer I have Linux and Windows 10. 
And I don't wanna use a WinApi function, because probably something like it exists, I believe this can be done without this.

Comment: On Windows, you have to use the appropriate WinAPI calls to access the hardware. Linux has its own set of API's for that purpose.  There may be some cross-platform libraries out there that provide consistent interfaces across both operating systems, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @jwdonahue Is it impossible to write function to this for yourself?

Comment: "I don't wanna use a WinApi function", so you have to write your own equivalent to access the sound drivers. If you use [`playsound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) you don't even have to load the file.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, I'm going to do some research about my Windows 2000 laptop speaker driver (they can't be complicated). If it supposed be too hard I would use the PlaySound function.

Comment: Sorry I meant `PlaySound`. One of the function flags specifies that the data is in memory. You should at least use this function before you consider writing your own function.

Comment: @Davey, yup, you can always write your own drivers, but you'll still be calling WinAPI's to do that as well.